# iOS: Apple Mach-O Linker Errors after installing FBSDK v4.0.1 via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, linker-errors, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've just installed the latest Facebook SDK (4.0.1) via Cocoapods and I'm getting the following errors when I run my code, everything is fine up until this point. 
The only code I've entered is to do with the FBSDKShareKit.

The 3 Linker errors are with FBSDKAppInviteDialog, FBSDKAppInviteContent and also a Linker error with exit code 1:

[image]

I've checked and made sure I'm not importing .m files, I'm using:

`#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>`

Been looking around and nothing has worked, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in project settings "allow non modular included in framework modules" to YES

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was related to an error I had with adding an SDK via Cocoapods that I had already added partly to my project. Removing this and going back to an earlier snapshot of the project helped solve the problem.